# Conjoint analysis based on a orthogonal design

Tags: spss

I'm having some issues regarding a conjoint analysis. Excuse me if some of the terms I use are wrong, but it has been some time since I last worked with SPSS - and my teacher was Danish.

---

**Task object**

I am to make a series of concept travelpackages (attributes and attribute notes/levels). 
This far I've got things under control - I've reduced the number of packages from 81 to 9, with the help of 'orthogonal' design.

These 9 packages have been rated by some people (1-10), on a questionnaire.

Then I've been asked to write a syntax which evaluates my conjoint plan:

```
CONJOINT PLAN= 'C:\Users\MYNAME\DROBBOXFOLDER\Conjoint_cards.SAV'
/DATA='C:\Users\MYNAME\DROBBOXFOLDER\Respondents.SAV'

/SCORE=Card_1 TO Card_9

/SUBJECT=ID

/FACTORS= SMS Minutter Data Tryghed

/PRINT=ALL

/PLOT=ALL.
```

However I keep getting this error:

> SUBJECT SUBCOMMAND -- Subject variable is not on data file.
>
> Execution of this command stops.

At this point I've been to the dark pages of Google and back for an answer to what I am doing wrong, but nothing so far. The answer is probably staring me in the face. But I will appreciate any help or pointers as to what I'm doing wrong.

---

**Problem solved:** 
So apparently one shouldn't follow a guide to the letter. My datafile didn't contain a ID, so removing this from my syntax solved the problem.

Comment: This question would fit better on a programming- or SPSS-oriented site.  But have you checked the SPSS tutorial?  It gives pretty good explanations and examples.  Hard-to-find topics can be accessed via "Show me" links on the Help pages.

Comment: I think, since this seems to be purely a "how do I make this part of SPSS work" type question, it doesn't contain any statistical questions, only programming ones. As such it seems a better fit for stackoverflow. If you'd like to have it moved there (don't repost it there!), please flag it so a moderator can move it for you.